# Split substring in string

Tags: sql, regex, presto

I have emails records which includes characters like 'nr' and some number with it like examplenr@example.comnr122342 Here first nr is okay that , but after .com I want to get rid of this 'nr122342' part. I want to use SQL query to get rid of this  to get only the original email address. Please advise with appropriate SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX`;
`CHARINDEX` function returns the position of the expression you are looking, in your case 'nr'.

```
declare @txt as varchar(50) = 'example@example.comnr122342'

select LEFT(@txt, CHARINDEX('nr', @txt, 1)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Valerica, I have edited the question.  I am in Presto environment and unfortunately I can't use I CHARINDEX.

Comment: sorry mate ... Unfortunately I can't help you with that. Maybe if you google the equivalent of CHARINDEX function in presto you will find something :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `STUFF` and `CHARINDEX`, this can be possible:

```
SEELCT STUFF(Email, CHARINDEX('.com', Email, 1) + LEN('.com'), LEN(Email), '') AS Email
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try somthing like the following:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StringBeforeLastIndex(@source nvarchar(80), @pattern char)
   RETURNS nvarchar(80)
   BEGIN  
         DECLARE @lastIndex int
         SET @lastIndex = (LEN(@source)) -  CHARINDEX(@pattern, REVERSE(@source)) 

       RETURN SUBSTRING(@source, 0, @lastindex + 1) 

  END;  
  GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`regexp_extract`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract) function to extract everything in the string except for the last portion (`nr` followed by a number)

```sql
WITH data(x) AS (VALUES 'examplenr@example.comnr122342')
SELECT regexp_extract(x, '(.+)nr\d+$', 1)
FROM data
```

produces:

```
         _col0
-----------------------
 examplenr@example.com
(1 row)
```